# Implementing a Priority Queue with a sorted list

Tags: java

Just finished to write this implementation with a `LinkedList`. I know that this is an beginner implementation. There are certainly a lot of mistakes. I just want to know if anyone can tell me the cost of worst case for the `insert(K key, V value)` method. Should I stay in O(n)?

Edited with `addLast()` and `getLast()` methods in `LinkedList` and using `ListIterator` instead of `Iterator`.

public class SortedListPriorityQueue implements PriorityQueue {

```
protected List<Entry<K,V>> entries;
protected Comparator<K> c;

private static class MyEntry<K,V> implements Entry<K,V>{

    protected K key;
    protected V value;

    public MyEntry(K key, V value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}


/**
 * Crea la coda con il comparatore DefaultComparator
 */
public SortedListPriorityQueue() {
    entries = new LinkedList<Entry<K,V>>();
    c = new DefaultComparator<K>();
}

/* Utilizza un comparatore specifico
 public SortedListPriorityQueue(Comparator<K> comp) {}
*/

@Override
public int size() {
    return entries.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return entries.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public Entry<K, V> min() {
    if(entries.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Priority queue is empty");
    else return entries.get(0);
}

@Override
public Entry<K, V> removeMin() {
    if(entries.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Priority queue is empty");
    else return entries.remove(0);

}

@Override
public Entry<K, V> insert(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> new_entry = new MyEntry<K,V>(key, value);

    insertEntry(new_entry);
    return new_entry;
}

private void insertEntry(Entry<K, V> e) {
    //caso base1: lista vuota
    if(entries.isEmpty()){
        entries.add(e);
        return;
    }

    // caso base2: inserisce alla fine della lista
    else if(c.compare(e.getKey(), ((LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>) entries).getLast().getKey()) > 0){
        ((LinkedList<Entry<K,V>>) entries).addLast(e);
        return;
    }

    ListIterator<Entry<K,V>> it = entries.listIterator();
    Entry<K,V> current = null;

    while(it.hasNext()){
        current = it.next();
        if(c.compare(e.getKey(), current.getKey()) < 0){
            it.add(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Insertion is `O(n)` The builtin PriorityQueue is `O(ln N)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your worst-case insert time is `O(n)` - inserting something that appears near the end of the list.  You spend `O(n)` time to find the correct index, then `O(n)` time inside `LinkedList.add` to insert it.

Answer (score 1):

Priority Queue can be implemented with O(log n) insertion using a Heap Implementation

Comment: Yep, I know and the heap it's a easier implementation!

Answer (score 0):

The cost of the worst case is linear, and it's determinated by the amount of entries you have -1 , because it's when you have to insert before the last element in the list. So it's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's `O(n)`.

But note that a constant multiplier of `n` is not optimal, because  `get(int)` and `add(int, T)` for `LinkedList` are `O(n)` as well, but you can replace them with `O(1)` operations - `getLast()`, `addLast()` and `ListIterator.add()`. That is, now it takes `O(n)` steps to find a place for a new entry and `O(n)` steps to actually insert it, but you can modify your implementation to find a place in `O(n)` and insert in `O(1)`.

Such a replacement won't change asymptotic complexity of your algorithm (it's still `O(n)`), but it would improve typical actual performance of your algorithm.

And, of course, for practical use it's better to use heap-based implementations (such as a built-in one) that provide `O(ln n)` insertion and removal.

Comment: Are you sure that `addLast()` and `getLast()` are both `O(1)` in a `LinkedList`? I thought those were methods that did the same thing of the others add scrolling through the list until the end.

Comment: @FabioCarello: From javadoc: "All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list." And doubly-linked list usually has a direct reference to its last entry.

Comment: Ok, now i remember this! There will be a pointer on the first node and on the last. Thanks!